# How to convert to millions in Mac:Numbers?

Tags: mac, ms-office, numbers, formatting

I understand in Microsoft Excel you would use the format string $#.##,," M"

so that

12,271,359 would appear as 12.27M

I am alittle confused with the Numbers app on Mac (the excel equivalent) and I do not have Excel on Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Custom Format,  Number…

Keep the default [#,###] it will auto-add
Drag in a decimal [.##]
Drag in a Scale [K] & use the drop menu to change to millions

[image]